# Using "suite" for a number of documents

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I recently received a letter from my solicitor which contained this statement:

> I am waiting to receive the suite of documents.

I've never heard this before; can you use *suite* for a number of documents?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see why not.

Although the OED does not indicate a specific sense for ***suite*** which relates to documents (it does have one for a *suite* of computer programs) it does indicate under sense 2a:

*A succession or series; in earlier use often applied to a series of publications; now chiefly said of series of specimens*. Unfortunately all the examples it gives are from before the 20th century, the four most recent being:

> 1845   S. Judd Margaret i. ii. 10   His laughter exposed a suite of
>   fair white teeth.
>
> 1858   Thackeray Virginians xxx,   There is nothing so flattering in
>   the world as a good suite of trumps.
>
> 1864   J. C. Atkinson Stanton Grange 295   A suite of tree-sparrow's
>   eggs, not less than 20 in number.
>
> 1874   H. M. Westropp Man. Precious Stones 3   The colour suite [of
>   diamonds] is, however, extensive.

Hence it would not seem out of tune with this historic sense for a professional, such as a solicitor, to ascribe the term ***suite*** to a group of documents that formed part of a set. Though I suppose the solicitor could equally well have said 'set'.

Comment: NGram shows an increase in usage in recents years of 'suite of documents': https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suite+of+documents&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuite%20of%20documents%3B%2Cc0. An example of usage: https://www.enisa.europa.eu/activities/risk-management/current-risk/bcm-resilience/bcm-approach/prioritize-recovery/suite-of-documents